# Polynomial expansion of a linear transformation (alternative proof)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, alternative-proof

This is the problem 35.3 from Halmos's *'Finite-Dimensional Vector Spaces'*.

Let $\mathscr{P}_n$ be the set of all polynomials of degree less or equal to $n-1$, having complex coefficients (together with the identically zero polynomial, $\mathscr{P}_n$ forms a vector space).

> Let $A$ be a linear transformation on $\mathscr{P}_n$, such that
>   $Ax(t) = x(t+1)$ for every $x \in \mathscr{P}_n$. Prove that if $D$ is the differential operator, then
>   \begin{gather}
> \tag{$\star$}
> 1+\frac{D}{1!}+\frac{D^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{D^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=A
> \label{eq}
> \end{gather}

**Proof**

The proof follows by induction. The base case for $n=1$ is straightforward to verify. Suppose that \eqref{eq} holds for $n$. Then, for $n+1$, observe that any polynomial $x$ in $\mathscr{P}_{n+1}$ can be written as $x=y+\alpha_n t^n$, with $y \in \mathscr{P}_n$. Then,
\begin{align}
Ax=A\big(y+\alpha_n t^n\big)&=y(t+1)+A(\alpha_nt^n)\\
&=y(t+1)+\alpha_n\big(t^n+\frac{n!}{1!(n-1)!}t^{n-1}+\frac{n!}{2!(n-2)!}t^{n-2}+\cdots+1\big)\\
&=y(t+1)+\alpha_n(t+1)^n\\
&=x(t+1)
\end{align}

**I)** Is the proof correct?

**II)** I would be interested in an alternative -more intuitive- proof for the above problem. For example, the polynomial expansion of the operator $A$ resembles the one of the exponential function. Is there anything in common there? What if we had a more general translation, like $x(t+c)$? Again, I can see what's happening when I carry out the computations, but I wonder if there is a more intuitive proof, unveiling something more interesting.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps slightly more intuitive to use the fact that these are linear operators and so we only need prove identities for individual powers of $t$.

Consider the infinite series for $e^D$. Acting on $t^k$ it is immediate that this produces $(t+1)^k$.

Re. the question about $x(t+c)$, the same argument proves this transform is $e^{cD}$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just neglected the most important property.. it's so simple that way..